# Wifi stick for Raspberry Pi 2

Tags: raspbian, wifi, ubuntu

I have bought a Raspberry PI 2 bundle, which contained an Edimax ew-7811un wifi stick. Unfortunately it is not working well with the Raspbian OS. It is horribly slow (4-10 Kbyte/s). I have tried several solutions and nothing worked.

I tried with Ubuntu Mate, there it got always disconnected after a while.

Can you recommend any USB Wifi Stick which:

- you have used and works fine
- has a speed of ~150Mbit/s
- there is no struggling with setting it up with Raspbian
- if it also works with [Ubuntu Mate](https://ubuntu-mate.org/raspberry-pi/) it would be great.

Size is not that critical, so it can be also something bigger than the Edimax. If there is some setup process of the stick, please refer to some install guide if there is any.

Comment: That Edimax adapter is just about the most commonly used USB wifi dongle for the Pi. It's *really* well supported. If it's not working then it's plausible something is wrong with your underlying system, or that there are external factors causing WiFi problems. If that's the case, a new WiFi dongle is unlikely to help.

Comment: I tried with the original raspbian coming with my bundle. I plugged in my dongle, attached to my wifi, and its slow like hell. Not sure what I did wrong.

Comment: It can be tricky to diagnose. I'd strongly recommend a careful look over all of the elements of your system, and some basic [tests](https://rasspberrypi.wordpress.com/2012/09/09/wifi-tools-for-raspberry-pi/) of your existing adapter.

Comment: Possibly an insufficient power supply related issue? I've seen many questions about USB Wi-Fi not working as well as expected, and often it is due to the additional power drain on the PSU by the USB Wi-Fi stick. What is the curent capacity of the PSU that you are using at the moment? Maybe try using a larger (i.e. greater current capacity) power supply? Test the stick in a laptop, as see if it as slow as it is when used with the Pi.

Comment: So it seems that it is also horribly slow with my Windows 10 desktop. It must be a defect.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The edimax dongle did not show more speed in a windows 10 machine as 1 Mbps. So I think it was defect.

I have bought however [Asus N10 Nano](https://www.asus.com/Networking/USBN10_NANO/) dongles, and I can confirm, that it works out of the box with Windows 10 on PC, witn Raspbian and Ubuntu Mate on Raspberry 2.

Answer (score 1):

Like a comment mentioned, it's either your system or your environment. Or, you simply got a bad stick.

Here's a checklist on what to look for:

- Interference

  - baby monitors, a buttload of nearby WiFi hotspots, microwaves, anything using the 2.4 GHz spectrum)
- Error messages (`dmesg` is a good place to start)
- The environment itself

  - Is your WiFi device and your Access point behind a block of lead? If it is, you have a problem.
  - A lot of walls (or floors if in a multi-story building) will definitely hamper signals to the point that both devices agree on using a very low-bandwidth connection.
- The stick

  - Does it work properly when used on your PC or laptop? (in a radio-quiet location, like in the woods/beach)

I can't really diagnose it with your given info. Some configuration details and error messages (if any) would be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

You can also try WiFi sticks with **Ralink Chipsets** for instance **RT5370 series** based [LogiLink WL0145](https://www.reichelt.nl/WLAN-Adapter/LOGILINK-WL0145/3/index.html?ACTION=3&GROUPID=5839&ARTICLE=118520)

They work perfectly with Raspberry Pi 2